# Disposing of object context when implementing a repository (DAL) and Mocking DAL for TDD

Tags: entity-framework, unit-testing, tdd

I am running into an issue where I can't figure out how to properly dispose of my object context I am creating every time I instantiate a new object.

```
public class OrderBLL{

     var _iOrderLineDal;

     public OrderBLL(){
         _iOderLineDal = new OrderLineDal(new entityOBject(dbconnectionstring);
     }

     public OrderBLL(iOrderLineDal mockOrderLineDal){
         _iOrderLineDal = mockOrderLineDal;
     }
}
```

So the problem is, that every 30 seconds my service creates a new instance of the OrderBLL and then runs a method to see if there are any new orders in the Data base.

So every 30 seconds I create a new entityObject that is not being disposed of. the old implementation of the code was written using the using statement.

```
public bool HasNewOrders(){

    using(var entityObject = new entityObject(dbconnectionString)){
       var newOrders = entityObject.GetNewOrders();
   }
   //some logic
}
```

The problem with using this using statement is I cannot mock out the entityObject and easily write unit tests on any methods inside this OrderBLL class.

I tried disposing of it with a dispose method inside the OrderLineDal and once i got the data called dispose. That worked well the first iteration but the following iterations, the next 30 seconds, it would say that the entityObject was disposed of and cannot be used. (doesn't make sense to me, since I am creating a new one every time?)

Is there a way I can implement this repository pattern and still dispose of all the new entityObjects so I can mock the DAL out for unit testing?

I am working with EF 4. and it was not set up Code First, so I do not have POCO.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you would want to create your context outside of your OrderBLL (search google for Repository pattern).

```
public class OrderRepository : IOrderRepository, IDisposable
{
    private readonly IOrderDBContext _dbContext;
    // poor mans dependency injection
    public OrderRepository() : this(new OrderDbContext("YourConnectionString")
    {}

    public OrderRepository(IOrderDBContext dbContext)
    {
        if (dbContext == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("dbContext");
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public bool GetNewOrders(){
        return _dbContext.Orders.Where(o => o.IsNew==true);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
      if (_dbContext != null) _dbContext.dispose();
    }
}

public class OrderBLL : IOrderBLL
{
    private readonly IOrderRepository _repository;

    public OrderRepository(IOrderRepository repository)
    {
        if (repository == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("dbContext");
        _repository = repository;
    }

    public bool HasNewOrders(){
        var newOrders = _repository.GetNewOrders();
        if (newOrders==null) return false;
        return newOrders.Count() > 0;
    }

}


[Test]
public void HasNewOrders_GivenNoNNewOrdersRetunedFromRepo_ReturnsFalse()
{
  // test using nunit and nsubstitute

  // Arrange
  var repository = Substitue.For<IOrderRepository>();
  var emptyOrderList = new List<Order>();
  repository.GetNewOrders().Returns();
  var orderBLL = new OrderBLL(repository);
  // Act
  var result = orderBLL.HasNewOrders();
  // Assert
  Assert.Equals(false, result);
}
```

Now you can inject your context into this class and easily test your business logic.  Eventually you will need to create your dbContext and should also always expose this.  I would suggest having a look at a DI container like Castle Windsor to manage the life of your objects, although in a service you may just want to manually create and dispose your context as close to the code entry point as possible (e.g. in the main method)

Comment: This is what I was attempting to do. However I didn't understand how to dispose of the context that is being created. I will look into using Castle Windsor. In the meantime i'm wrapping the OrderBLL in a using statement, and the OrderBLL inherits Idisposable. Then I have a public dispose method in OrderBLL that disposes the _dbcontext. Will the using staetment call the dispose method i created in the OrderBLL?

Comment: If OrderBLL implements IDisposable then you would need to call dispose on the dbContext in the OrderBLL.dispose() method.  You would end up needing to wrap the OrderBLL in a using statement.  For testing I would suggest having a look at a mocking library such as NSubstitute (This is where your interfaces become important). I will updated the answer above to show how.